# Does Kotlin have an identity function?

Tags: kotlin

Scala has a generic `identity` function in the Predef:

```
def identity[A](x: A): A
```

Does Kotlin have a similar facility in the standard library? Of course I could simply use `{ it }` instead, but I find `identity` easier to read, and instantiating all those lambdas is a little wasteful.

I must be able to use this `identity` function in places where a function `(Foo) -> Foo` is expected, for any type `Foo`. Is such a function even possible in Kotlin's type system? (In the case of Scala, there is an implicit conversion that wraps the method inside a function object or something.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no such function at the moment, but you can easily define it yourself:

```
fun <T> identity(x: T): T = x
```

If you think there are enough use cases for this function to be declared in Kotlin standard library, please file an issue at [youtrack.jetbrains.com](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com). Thanks!

Comment: You need to write `::identity` in order to instantiate a function object from a function. This is similar to Java's method references.

Comment: Hey! I've found a use-case for such a function! It is the `list.toMap(A, B)` function as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935470/how-to-convert-list-to-map-in-kotlin/32938733#32938733

Consider that there would be `fun it(x) = x`, than `list.toMap(::it, {it.length})` converts a list to a map where the elements are the keys.

Answer (score 21):

If you need to pass the identity function as a parameter to another function, you can simply use `{ it }`. For example, it you have a List<List<String>> and want to flatten it to a List<String>, you could use:

```
list.flatMap(identity)
```

where `identity` is the identity function. This can be written as:

```
list.flatMap { it }
```

This is equivalent to:

```
list.flatMap { x -> x }
```

The alternative would be to define the identity function somewhere, such as:

```
val identity: (List<String>) -> List<String> = { it }
```

But we can't create a generic `val`, so we would have to define an identity function for each type. The solution, (as it is done in Java `Function` interface) is to define it as a constant function:

```
fun <A> identity(): (A) -> A = { it }
```

and use it as:

```
list.flatMap(identity)
```

Of course, it is much easier to write:

```
list.flatMap { it }
```

Declaring an identity function once for all (that would work for all types) is not possible because it would have to be parameterized. What is possible is to use a function returning this identity function:

```
fun <T> identity(): (T) -> T  = { it }
```

Although it does the job, it is not very helpful since one has now to write:

```
list.flatMap(identity())
```

Comment: Easier to write, yes, but there are use cases where having a defined identify function is incredibly useful (such as a general-purpose sequence of stream  operations with an optional filter stage).

Comment: What would be the type of this function? A generic value function would not be possible because there would be no information for inferring the type. A generic `fun` function returning a value function is possible, but probably not worth it.

Comment: Fair point. The use case I was attempting to use it for was supplying a identity func to Collection.filter(), which happens to return Boolean. In that case, I ended up using `{ true }`, but that's not really an identity function.

Comment: However, as a matter of fact, I think you can fake your way toward a generic by using an extension function: `fun <T: Any> T.identity(): T = this`
And then to call it, you would use `Any::identity`

Comment: Interesting solution!