# How to convert List to Map in Kotlin?

Tags: dictionary, kotlin

For example I have a list of strings like:

```
val list = listOf("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

and I want to convert it to a map, where the strings are the keys.

I know I should use the `.toMap()` function, but I don't know how, and I haven't seen any examples of it.

Answer (score 486, accepted):

You have two choices:

The first and most performant is to use `associateBy` function that takes two lambdas for generating the key and value, and inlines the creation of the map:

```
val map = friends.associateBy({it.facebookId}, {it.points})
```

The second, less performant, is to use the standard `map` function to create a list of `Pair` which can be used by `toMap` to generate the final map:

```
val map = friends.map { it.facebookId to it.points }.toMap()
```

Comment: thank you. is it faster because it creates a map, and not converts a list of pairs to a map, like in my example?

Comment: @lordScone Exactly, the allocations of  `Pair` instances might be very costly for big collections

Comment: I don't see `.toMap()` function

Comment: Using the second option here, `map { it to it.foo }` and then `toMap()`, IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) will suggest automatically converting it to **`associateWith { it.foo }`**. This is the simplest option for the case OP was asking about: the original list items become the map keys.

Answer (score 80):

## From `List` to `Map` with `associate` function

With Kotlin 1.3, `List` has a function called [`associate`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html). `associate` has the following declaration:

```
fun <T, K, V> Iterable<T>.associate(transform: (T) -> Pair<K, V>): Map<K, V>
```

> Returns a `Map` containing key-value pairs provided by `transform` function applied to elements of the given collection.

*Usage:*

```
class Person(val name: String, val id: Int)

fun main() {
    val friends = listOf(Person("Sue Helen", 1), Person("JR", 2), Person("Pamela", 3))
    val map = friends.associate({ Pair(it.id, it.name) })
    //val map = friends.associate({ it.id to it.name }) // also works

    println(map) // prints: {1=Sue Helen, 2=JR, 3=Pamela}
}
```

---

## From `List` to `Map` with `associateBy` function

With Kotlin, `List` has a function called [`associateBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html). `associateBy` has the following declaration:

```
fun <T, K, V> Iterable<T>.associateBy(keySelector: (T) -> K, valueTransform: (T) -> V): Map<K, V>
```

> Returns a `Map` containing the values provided by `valueTransform` and indexed by `keySelector` functions applied to elements of the given collection.

*Usage:*

```
class Person(val name: String, val id: Int)

fun main() {
    val friends = listOf(Person("Sue Helen", 1), Person("JR", 2), Person("Pamela", 3))
    val map = friends.associateBy(keySelector = { person -> person.id }, valueTransform = { person -> person.name })
    //val map = friends.associateBy({ it.id }, { it.name }) // also works

    println(map) // prints: {1=Sue Helen, 2=JR, 3=Pamela}
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between associate and associateBy? Would I want to prefer to use one over the other, seeing that they produce the same result?

Comment: These are the little things why I've come to love Kotlin so much. Thanks!

Comment: @waynesford, ```associateBy``` returns a map where the you have control over the ids, meaning that the values will be the elements of the collection you call ```associateBy``` upon. ```associate``` let you take control over both ids and values.

Comment: @ArthurBertemes what you describe is the version of `associateBy` that takes only one parameter (the key selector). This answer describes the version of `associateBy` that takes two parameters (key and value selectors) and seems to do exactly the same thing as `associate` - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76604016/are-associate-and-associateby-the-same) for the main differences

Answer (score 26):

If you have **duplicates** in your list that you don't want to lose, you can do this using `groupBy`.

Otherwise, like everyone else said, use `associate/By/With` (which in the case of duplicates, I believe, will only return the last value with that key).

An example grouping a list of people by age:

```
class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)

fun main() {
    val people = listOf(Person("Sue Helen", 31), Person("JR", 25), Person("Pamela", 31))

    val duplicatesKept = people.groupBy { it.age }
    val duplicatesLost = people.associateBy({ it.age }, { it })

    println(duplicatesKept)
    println(duplicatesLost)
}
```

Results:

```
{31=[Person@41629346, Person@4eec7777], 25=[Person@3b07d329]}
{31=Person@4eec7777, 25=Person@3b07d329}
```

Answer (score 20):

- Convert a Iteratable Sequence Elements to a Map in kotlin ,
- associate vs associateBy vs associateWith:

*Reference:[Kotlin Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html)

1- associate (to set  both Keys & Values): Build a map that can set key & value elements :

```
IterableSequenceElements.associate { newKey to newValue } //Output => Map {newKey : newValue ,...}
```

> If any of two pairs would have the same key the last one gets added to the map.
>
> The returned map preserves the entry iteration order of the original array.

2- associateBy (just set Keys by calculation): Build a map that we can set new Keys, analogous elements will be set for values

```
IterableSequenceElements.associateBy { newKey } //Result: => Map {newKey : 'Values will be set  from analogous IterableSequenceElements' ,...}
```

3- associateWith (just set Values by calculation): Build a map that we can set new Values, analogous elements will be set for Keys

```
IterableSequenceElements.associateWith { newValue }  //Result => Map { 'Keys will be set from analogous IterableSequenceElements' : newValue , ...}
```

Example from Kotlin tips :
[image]

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`associate`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate.html) for this task:

```
val list = listOf("a", "b", "c", "d")
val m: Map<String, Int> = list.associate { it to it.length }
```

In this example, the strings from `list` become the keys and their corresponding lengths (as an example) become the values inside the map.

Answer (score 0):

That have changed on the RC version.

I am using `val map =  list.groupByTo(destinationMap, {it.facebookId}, { it -> it.point })`