# How do I create a map from 2 arrays?

Tags: kotlin

I have a string array and an integer array. How do I create a map using the first as keys and the second as values?

```
val keys = arrayOf("butter", "milk", "apples")
val values = arrayOf(5, 10, 42)
val map: Map<String, Int> = ???
```

[How to convert List to Map in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935470/how-to-convert-list-to-map-in-kotlin) doesn't solve this problem; I have 2 arrays and want a single map.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert List to Map in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935470/how-to-convert-list-to-map-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can zip together the arrays to get a list of pairs (`List<Pair<String, Int>>`), and then use `toMap` to get your map.

Like this:

```
val keys = arrayOf("butter", "milk", "apples")
val values = arrayOf(5, 10, 42)

val map: Map<String, Int> = 
             keys.zip(values) // Gives you [("butter", 5), ("milk", 10), ("apples", 42)]
                 .toMap()     // This is an extension function on Iterable<Pair<K, V>>
```

Comment: Good, I just needed to change `values.toList()` on penultimate line.

Comment: Or probably even better: `values.asIterable()`

Comment: if key collisions happen, only the last added value is retained.

Comment: @tausif Yes, but this happens on toMap stadium and can be escaped, if needed

Comment: This method is a shortened variant of a complicated way with a null lambda expression. IMHO, (keys zip values).toMap() would be better, for it is basically simple and is not an abbreviation of a much more complicated method.

Comment: @Gangnus Sorry, what? There's no null-lambda in play here. The only difference between `keys.zip(values)` and `keys zip values` is the use of infix notation.

Comment: @marstran And the byte code is the same, are you sure? Thank you.

Comment: @Gangnus Yes, both are just a function call to this `zip`-function: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html#zip

Answer (score 1):

According to kotlin
 [Constructing Collections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/constructing-collections.html)
-> creating a short-living Pair object, is not recommended only if performance isn't critical and to quote: "To avoid excessive memory usage, use alternative ways. For example, you can create a mutable map and populate it using the write operations. The apply() function can help to keep the initialization fluent here."

since I'm not much of an expert I run on to these code and maybe this should work better?:

```
    val numbersMap = mutableMapOf<String,Int>()
        .apply{ for (i in 1.. 5)  this["key$i"] = i }
    println(numbersMap)

    //result = {key1=1, key2=2, key3=3, key4=4}
```

or to adjust it to question above - something like this:

```
    val keys = arrayOf("butter", "milk", "apples")
    val values = arrayOf(5, 10, 42)
    val mapNumber = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
            .apply { for (i in keys.indices) this[keys[i]] = values[i] }
    println(mapNumber)
```