# Kotlin: How to convert list to map with list?

Tags: kotlin

I have a list as below
{("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3), ("a", 4)}

I want to convert it to a map of list as below
{("a" (1, 4)),  ("b", (2)), ("c", (3)))}

i.e. for a, we have a list of 1 and 4, since the key is the same.

The answer in
[How to convert List to Map in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935470/how-to-convert-list-to-map-in-kotlin) only show unique value (instead of duplicate one like mine).

I tried `associateBy` in Kotlin

```
    data class Combine(val alpha: String, val num: Int)
    val list = arrayListOf(Combine("a", 1), Combine("b", 2), Combine("c", 3), Combine("a", 4))
    val mapOfList = list.associateBy ( {it.alpha}, {it.num} )
    println(mapOfList)
```

But doesn't seems to work. How could I do it in Kotlin?

Comment: each entry in the map would be String as the key and the list as the value?

Comment: Right... I can't find of a good function to do it, except for the conventional way of looping though using immutable collection. Looks not concise.

Comment: You need to do `associateBy({it.alpha}, {it.num})`

Comment: Not helping, the "a" will only contain 4. What I want is "a" with (1, 4).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Code

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    data class Combine(val alpha: String, val num: Int)
    val list = arrayListOf(Combine("a", 1), Combine("b", 2), Combine("c", 3), Combine("a", 4))
    val mapOfList = list.associateBy ( {it.alpha}, {it.num} )
    println(mapOfList)
    val changed = list
        .groupBy ({ it.alpha }, {it.num})
    println(changed)
}
```

## Output

```
{a=4, b=2, c=3}
{a=[1, 4], b=[2], c=[3]}
```

## How it works

- First it takes the list
- It groups the `Combine`s by their alpha value to their `num` values

Comment: Great! `groupBy` is indeed the answer. I improve the answer with `val result = list.groupBy { it.alpha }.mapValues { it.value.map { it.num } }` Thanks. Vote up for you and tick. (If you think my question helps others as well... do give a vote to it :)

Comment: Note that there's `groupBy` overload with two selectors: key and value, so you don't have to call `mapValue` in the end: `groupBy({ it.apha }, { it.num })`

Comment: The collection API cheatsheet https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/kotlin-collection-functions-cheat-sheet-975371a96c4b?source=friends_link&sk=5549a09ff615dbfd02694807e4f9d86a

Answer (score 18):

You may group the list by `alpha` first and then map the value to `List<Int>`:

```
data class Combine(val alpha: String, val num: Int)
val list = arrayListOf(Combine("a", 1), Combine("b", 2), Combine("c", 3), Combine("a", 4))
val mapOfList = list
        .groupBy { it.alpha }
        .mapValues { it.value.map { it.num } }
println(mapOfList)
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Your came in late a bit. Else I would give you a tick. Anyway, I upvote your answer!

Comment: If you think my question could help others, do upvote my question ya... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly more concise version of Jacky Choi's solution.

It combines the grouping and the transforming into one call to `groupBy()`.

```
val mapOfList = list
        .groupBy (
            keySelector = { it.name },
            valueTransform = { it.num },
        )
```