# kotlin merge list of map

Tags: kotlin

I want to group by id.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "a"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "b"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "c"
    }
]
```

The results should be as follows:

```
{
    "1": "a",
    "2": "b",
    "3": "c"
}
```

What is the most idiomatic way of doing this in Kotlin?

Comment: What you have shown is just json. What do you want in Kotlin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert List to Map in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935470/how-to-convert-list-to-map-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question only shows JSON, so I'm not sure if this is about JSON serialization or Kotlin. Since it's tagged `kotlin`, I'm assuming you're already deserializing the initial list to Kotlin with something like this

```kotlin
data class NamedThing(val id: Int, val name: String)

val list: List<NamedThing> = TODO("somehow you're getting a list of those here")
```

If you already have this, you can easily create a map from this list using:

```kotlin
val map = list.associate { it.id to it.name }
```

Comment: I think he wants a string key. `it.id.toString()` or `"${it.id}"` will be better i guess.

Comment: True, but JSON keys *have to* be quoted, so I guessed in the OP the string keys were more a constraint than a requirement. In Kotlin, we can have int keys so if the question is not about JSON I believe it's better this way.