# Kotlin: How to convert a list of object to a Set based on object values

Tags: android, kotlin, collections, java-stream, flatmap

Please suggest better ways to convert routes to routesMap.

```
lateinit var routes: List<Pair<String, String>>
val routesMap = HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>
routes.forEach { 
    routesMap.getOrPut(it.first) { ArrayList<String>() }.add(it.second)
}
```

Comment: Title of the question is about Set but body is about Map.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935470/how-to-convert-list-to-map-in-kotlin same question already exists, so closing this. Thanks @broot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This operation is often called "grouping by" and can be easily done in Kotlin using [groupBy()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) extension:

```kotlin
val routesMap = routes.groupBy({ it.first }, { it.second })
```