# convert a List of objects to a Map in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

What is the most efficient way to convert a List of objects to a Map in Kotlin. Given a list of objects, a map is a structure that allows for efficient retrieval of values associated with a specific key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert List to Map in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935470/how-to-convert-list-to-map-in-kotlin). It does have almost the same exact title, quite easy to find I'd say.

Comment: Not just the fact that it's probably a duplicate, but that both it and the duplicate are underspecified (and this one is even more underspecified than the dup target): What should be the keys and values of the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function to do this is actually built in to Kotlin. It's called [`associateBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate-by.html).

> ```
> inline fun <T, K> Iterable<T>.associateBy(
>     keySelector: (T) -> K
> ): Map<K, T>
> ```

It takes a single argument, mapping an element of type `T` to the desired key of type `K`.

So, if you had a list of `Person` objects, and each person had a `name` you wanted to index by, you could write

```
personList.associateBy { it.name }
```

to get the map from names to people.

Note that there also exists a more general function called [`associate`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate.html), which maps a `T`  to a key *and* a value (where the value may or may not be equal to the original `T` value). This is useful if you want to perform a mapping *and* produce an associative container at the same time. But since it sounds like your use case involves indexing existing objects, `associateBy` is probably sufficient.

Comment: Can you prove that this way is the most efficient way?

Comment: Sure. The docs don't list a big-O complexity, but we can take a look at the source code and verify that [the function is a straight for-loop](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/f3385fbdcb8b9dc29661a8a4973c855cdcf73767/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Collections.kt#L1221) which is `O(n)` in the list size. And since we have to iterate over the data at least once to transform it, we can't do better than `O(n)`. So if "most efficient" is defined as "best computational complexity", then we've already hit it.