# Are associate and associateBy the same?

Tags: kotlin

I'm confused by the two-parameter variant of `associateBy`:

```
inline fun <T, K, V> Iterable<T>.associateBy(
    keySelector: (T) -> K,
    valueTransform: (T) -> V
): Map<K, V>
```

This seems to do exactly the same thing as `associate`, but with alternative syntax:

```
inline fun <T, K, V> Iterable<T>.associate(
    transform: (T) -> Pair<K, V>
): Map<K, V>
```

Equivalent usages:

```
listOf("cat", "dog", "mouse").associateBy({it.toUpperCase()}, {it.length})
listOf("cat", "dog", "mouse").associate({it.toUpperCase() to it.length})
```

Are these two functions just alternative syntax for the same thing, or is there a specific technical reason they both exist separately, e.g. is each one designed to be used in a different circumstance than the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are just alternative ways of doing the same thing. I can think of some situations where you would prefer one of them though.

If the keys and values come from a time consuming function that you don't want to run twice for each element, then `associate` is more suitable:

```
list.associate {
    val result = timeConsumingFunction(it) // timeConsumingFunction only gets run once per element
    result.property1 to result.property2
}
```

If the keys and values map nicely to property/method references of the elements, `associateBy` looks nicer to people who really likes property/method references (e.g. me):

```
list.associateBy(Foo::property1, Foo::property2)
```

`associatedBy` also avoids creating the `Pair` object that `associate` would require, though this is a micro-optimisation in most cases.