# Kotlin a member reference to return the object itself

Tags: lambda, reflection, kotlin, method-reference

Is there a way to write a member/method reference to return the object itself in Kotlin? That is to say, it can simplify and replace the following lambda:

```
{ it }
```

Comment: I think you should be able to use the answer from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336436/does-kotlin-have-an-identity-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a built in way as far as I know. Best you could do is write a function that does this once, and then refer to that when you need it, e.g.

```
inline fun <T> identity(t: T) = t
```

And then usage like so:

```
"foo".let(::identity) // still "foo"
```